# how to establish a database connection with an .xml file using JDBC Java

Tags: java, xml, jdbc

As the title indicates, I have the connection information to my database located in a .xml file. Here the full code of this file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<context>

<Resource url="jdbc:sqlserver://LAPTOP..;database=test" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" password="cgy55wH-..." username="sa" nomBDD="test" typeConn="SQL Server"/>

<Chemin fileSauve="truc\Export\" file="truc\Export\"/>

</context>
```

I can't figure out how to retrieve the information from my java code. (using JDBC)
As a first step, I started to develop a function that allows me to confirm the existence of the file.

Here a part of the code :

```java
    public String searchFile() throws Exception {
        String retour = "ko";
        File fichier;
        for (File lment : File.listRoots()) {
            fichier = new File(lment + "\\XFiles\\Conf\\init.xml");
            if (fichier.exists()) {
                cheminFichier=lment+"\\XFiles\\Conf\\init.xml";
                retour = "ok";
            }
        }
        return retour;
    }
```

I'm open to any suggestion or idea which allows me to undertand and solve this problem.

Comment: Parse the xml (lots of libs for that out there) - store the values you need for the DB connection, and use them to open your jdbc connection

Comment: Okay I see, I can use libs like XPath  (to locate xml) and then : 

```String url = (String) xpath.compile("//config//jdbc//url").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);``` Something like it ?

Comment: It's just to retrieve password, url, etc.. and then I concat them with the :
```conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName="+database+";integratedSecurity=true;",user,password); //récupérer les informations de la connexion (serveur, BDD...)```

Comment: Similar: [*Persisting WAR Database Configuration?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60471531/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI)

Your XML looks like a definition file from a [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) such as [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat).

If so, you should be using the [Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) API built into Java to access the information indirectly.

Some people load the database info in an [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) server or a similar [directory service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service), reachable from your Java code via JNDI.

Tomcat and similar [web containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) bundle their own directory service, reached by your Java code via [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface). The key idea here is **no [hard-coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) of details that change at deployment time**. Your web app code should not know anything about your particular web container, nor should your web app know anything about its configuration files. JNDI is the middle-man between your web app and the runtime deployment details. So when the database password changes, you need not re-compile your web app. When you or you admins change from Tomcat to [Payara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payara_Server), for example, you need not re-compile your web app.

So you would not in your code be directly opening an XML file. That reading and parsing of the XML file is the job of your web container.

You would be asking the JNDI service to provide you with a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object. From that data source, you call [`getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection()) to connect to database. This puts all of the configuration info responsibility in the hands of the sysadmin. The configuration is transparent to you as the programmer.

As for encrypting the password in the `Resource` tag of your XML configuration file: You don‘t. If you search the Web you will find articles explaining that to some point your quest for protection must end. If you encrypt the password there, you must still have a decryption key somewhere. So you must protect that decryption key by encrypting it, which means you need to protect *that* second key. And so on, [turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down). At some point you must have a locked-down system that is trustworthy.

Search Stack Overflow to learn more as this has been covered many times. The sister site Server Fault Stack Exchange might also have info.

Comment: Hello, thank you or this solution. I didn't know this technology and I will use it. 
Currently, I have an crypted password and I use an fonction which allows me to decrypt it. Is there also an option to get this password before to getConnection ?

Comment: For example, when I wrote this line of code (as you said, it puts all the desired configurations to the connection): 
```DataSource datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("....");```

What should I wrote into the lookup. My .xml file doesn't have a name.

Comment: @harili All these details have been covered multiple times on Stack Overflow, including posts by me regarding Tomcat. Read the [JNDI tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/TOC.html) by Oracle. And read the docs for your particular web container. It can be a little tricky getting all the pieces in place. But it is well worth the effort so you have separation between your app code and your deployment configuration. Tip: Learn to use the `site:stackoverflow.com blah blah` search terms in DuckDuckGo/Bing/Google. The Stack Overflow searching is biased to Questions over Answers.

Comment: @harili RE: encryption, see my edits to the Answer.